# How can I prove that this function is continuous at $0$?

Tags: general-topology

The classical example of a functions with only one point of continuity is 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x \in \mathbf{Q}, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

I only want to prove the continuity at $0$, using the definition in terms of open sets. Let $(a,b)$ be an open set containing $0$. I want to prove that the preimage of this interval is open in $\mathbf R$. But since every preimage contains the $0$ element, the preimage consists of all irrational numbers and the rational numbers of the interval $(a,b)$, but this set is not open. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To appeal to metric properties where only topological ones are involved might be seen as using the dark side of the Force but, to prove the precise statement you propose, I would simply write that $|f(x)|\le|x|$ for every $x$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$f$ is continuous at $x$ if the preimage of every open neighborhood of $f(x)$ **contains** an open neighborhood of $x$.  The preimage need not be open itself.

For a simpler example, let $g(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$, and let $g(x)=0$ when $x<0$.  Then $g$ is continuous at $x=1$, but the preimage of $(0,2)$ is $[0,\infty)$, which is not open in $\mathbb R$.  Nonetheless, the preimage contains the open neigborhood $(0,2)$ of $x=1$.

Translating this to $\varepsilon$s and $\delta$s, recall that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\{y:|x-y|<\delta\}\subseteq f^{-1}(\{y:|f(x)-y|<\varepsilon\})$.  Here $\{y:|x-y|<\delta\}$ is the neighborhood of $x$, and it is only required to be *contained in* the preimage of the neighborhood $\{y:|f(x)-y|<\varepsilon\}$ of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: What is the definition of continuity at a point in terms of open sets?  How does it differ from the global definition of continuity in terms of open sets?

Answer (score 3):

If a function is continuous **everywhere** then the pre-image of every open set under that function is open.

But in this problem it is *not* the case that the function is continuous everywhere, so one should not expect the pre-image of every open set to be open.