# prove that the indicator function $\chi$ is discontinuous at each point of cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

I really cannot formalize it: what I'd say is that the complement of cantor set ($E^c$) is open, so the preimage with $\chi$ of each neighbourhood of $1$ (which is open for def.) is the set $E$, which is closed. since the preimage of an open set is not open $\chi$ is discontinuous. can it holds? thanks!

Comment: What is $\chi$?

Comment: I'm guessing it is the characteristic function of the Cantor set.

Comment: yes, I've changed the title. thanks for hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've proved that if $U$ is open in $\mathbb R$ then $\chi^{-1}(U)$ is closed which proves that $\chi$ is not continuous. However I believe this does not prove it is discontinuous at *every* point. To argue this you would say that if $x\in C$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then $V$ contains a point not in $C$ (since $C$ has empty interior) and so $\chi(V)=\{0,1\}$. That contradicts the definition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165164/functions-between-topological-spaces-being-continuous-at-a-point) of continuity at $x$, which would require that for every neighborhood $U$ of $\chi(x)$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ so that $\chi(V)\subset U$.

Comment: The downvoter should explain their objection.

Comment: thanks. I couldn't find a proof with the definition of continuity using preimages!