# Show that $\tilde{g}$ is continuous on $X.$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $X$ is a separable and completely metrizable space. Assume that $g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
Denote $A = \{ x \in X: g(x)<0 \}.$
Define $\tilde{g}:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\tilde{g}(x)=g(x)$ if $x \in A$, $\tilde{g}(x) = 0$ if $x \not\in A.$

> Question: Show that $\tilde{g}$ is continuous on $X.$

It suffices to check at 'boundary' of $A$, since $g$ and $0$ are continuous functions.

I do not know how to check at boundary of a set. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a notion of checking [continuity at a point for a topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165164/functions-between-topological-spaces-being-continuous-at-a-point); although since both of your spaces are metrizable you could instead throw a metric on $X$ and work with the $\varepsilon-\delta$ version of continuity at a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If a map $f \colon X → Y$ is continuous on two closed subspaces $A, B ⊆ X$ covering $X$, i.e. $X = A ∪ B$, then it is continuous on all $X$.
2. So it suffices to check that $\tilde g$ is continuous on the closed sets $\operatorname{cls A}$ and $X \setminus A$ (as $A$ is open, being the preimage of an open set under a continuous function).
3. So it suffices to check that $\tilde g|_{\operatorname{cls} A} = g|_{\operatorname{cls} A}$, that is $g|_{∂A} = 0$.
4. Since $X$ is metrizable, so is $\operatorname{cls} A$. As $A ⊆ \operatorname{cls} A$ is dense, every point $x ∈ ∂A$ is the limit of a sequence in $A$. Note that $∂A ⊆ X \setminus A$, as $A$ is open in $X$, and so $g|_{∂A} ≥ 0$.

Comment: By the way, I don’t think there’s a need for $X$ to be *completely* metrizable or separable. Being metrizable should be enough (unless I am missing some subtle point).

Comment: What is the definition of $\partial A $?

Comment: @Idonknow It denotes the boundary of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $g$ is continuous, which intuitively means that is supposed to map close points close to each other. Formally this means that we obtain a $\delta$ such that [yadda yadda].

Notice that $\widetilde g$ maps close points either (1) equally close together or (2) closer together [if, say, g(point) is negative and g(other) is positive]. This gives us a strong guess as to a $\widetilde\delta$ that will work.

Comment: (Note that this hint does not directly answer the question of how you'd check the boundary of a set. I talked about that in the comment above but I think the idea is a bit of a red herring.)